# CRM Dynamics 2013 How to pass current logged as the record owner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a scenario in CRM where I created an MVC application that uploads a excel file, does some validation on the file, once the records are validated,it creates the new records in CRM, I need to know how can I handles the current logged in user in CRM so that that specific user performs the create and is then owner the records. I am currently using a CRM User which I created in AD, but I need this to be the logged in user who runs the process/app. Currently that CRM User owns all records upon upload, regardless which user uploaded. Please see my code below.

```
public ActionResult ImportDataToCRM(CRM_Embrace_IntegrationEntities1 db)
{
    CrmConnection conn = new CrmConnection("CRM");
    IOrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(conn);
    WhoAmIRequest whoReq = new WhoAmIRequest();
    WhoAmIResponse whoResp = (WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(whoReq);
    Guid userid = whoResp.UserId;
    var cleanClaimsFromDB = db.CleanSupplierClaims.Select(x => x).ToList();

    foreach (var claim in cleanClaimsFromDB)
    {
        new_supplierclaimsupdate CRMSupplierClaimsData = new new_supplierclaimsupdate()
        {
            new_Action = claim.Action.Trim(),
            new_InvoiceNumebr = claim.Line_Number.Trim(),
            new_TotalClaim = Convert.ToDecimal(claim.Total_Claim).ToString(),
            new_Currency = claim.Currency.Trim(),
            new_Supplier = claim.ClaimReference.Trim(),
            OwnerId = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, userid),
        };

        service.Create(CRMSupplierClaimsData);
    }
}
```

ConnectionString is:

```
<add name="CRM" connectionString="Url=https://serername/OrgName; Username=domain\CRM_User; Password=mypassword" />
```

I need this to be generic and not upload as CRM User but as the actual user who is running the application, please assist.

Comment: are you getting any errors with your above code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [OrganizationServiceProxy  CallerId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.callerid.aspx) property to set the user to pass on as the caller.

```
var service = new OrganizationService(conn);
var whoReq = new WhoAmIRequest();
var whoResp = (WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(whoReq);
var cleanClaimsFromDB = db.CleanSupplierClaims.Select(x => x).ToList();
var service = organizationService as OrganizationService;
if (service != null)
 {
    var serviceProxy = service.InnerService as OrganizationServiceProxy;
    if (serviceProxy == null) throw new InvalidCastException("invalid cast");
    serviceProxy.CallerId = whoResp.UserId; //The user GUID you want to pass as the caller         
 }

var cleanClaimsFromDB = db.CleanSupplierClaims.Select(x => x).ToList();
foreach (var claim in cleanClaimsFromDB)
{
    var CRMSupplierClaimsData = new new_supplierclaimsupdate()
    {
        new_Action = claim.Action.Trim(),
        new_InvoiceNumebr = claim.Line_Number.Trim(),
        new_TotalClaim = Convert.ToDecimal(claim.Total_Claim).ToString(),
        new_Currency = claim.Currency.Trim(),
        new_Supplier = claim.ClaimReference.Trim()
    };

    service.Create(CRMSupplierClaimsData);
}
```